# Why won't jQuery's load event fire on dynamically inserted script elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm dynamically inserting a script element using jQuery. The script loads as expected, but the load event does not fire.

```
jQuery('<script/>').attr({
    type : 'text/javascript',
    src : 'http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js'
}).appendTo('body').load(function(){
    /* This alert does not fire: */
    alert('I just loaded!');
});
```

If I use regular JavaScript to insert the element, the load event does fire and can be caught with jQuery.

```
var e = document.createElement('script'); 
e.type = 'text/javascript';
e.src = 'http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
document.body.appendChild(e);

jQuery(e).load(function(){
    /* This alert does fire: */
    alert('I just loaded!');
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not just use javascript.. jquery IS javascript, so what's the problem?

Comment: That's what I'm currently doing, but I'd still like to know why the jQuery implementation isn't working as expected. Hence the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the [`jQuery.getScript()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) method instead.

```
$.getScript('http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js',function(){
    alert('I just loaded!');
});
```

Or, on current versions of jQuery, using the promise pattern as below

```
$.getScript('http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js')
  .done(function(){
    alert('I just loaded!');
  })
  .fail(function(){
    console.log('script could not load');
  })
;
```

---

**EDIT:** Removed the code comment that was copied from the question, as it added confusion to the answer. Thanks to [@Jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/561545/jeff) for pointing it out.

Comment: You confused me with the "This alert does not fire", but after reading the OP again, I realized you just copied. Wouldnt it be a good idea to remove the "This alert does not fire", when your answer seeks to solve that issue? ;)

Comment: @Jeff: Ha! I didn't even read that! Yes, very good idea. Updating... Thanks. :o)

Comment: Hahah, no problem. Good to see that I am of SOME use on here, especially considering I have asked 64 questions :P

Comment: Thanks for your answer Patrick. It seems odd that we need to resort to a method that has the overhead of an XMLHttpRequest, rather than just being able to append the element to the DOM and bind to its load event.

Comment: @johnbillion: Yes, I think it's that jQuery sanitizes items added to the page, removing scripts, so the `appendTo` is erasing the script. Not sure why they do that. So you can do it all with jQuery, except for the `.appendTo()`.

Comment: Please explain why the OPs code does not work.  `getScript` is not a catch-all.  For example, if I had a string `<script src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>` and needed to inject that specifically (could not pick it apart).