# Why does DOM appendChild() fire on('load', ...) but jQuery append() does not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, onload

I have the following to snippets of code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.head.appendChild(
        $('<script />').attr('src', 'source.js').on('load', function() {
            ...
        })[0]
    );
});
```

This will fire the load handler.

Whereas using the normal jQuery `append()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('head').append(
        $('<script />').attr('src', 'source.js').on('load', function() {
            ...
        })
    );
});
```

This will not fire the load hander.

What am I missing: why does jQuery `append()` not work?

Is using `document.head.appendChild()` a bad idea?

NOTE: I can't use `$.getScript()`. The code will run on a local file system and chrome throws cross site script errors.

---

**Update**

Some people had trouble reading the compact style, so I used extra line feeds to clarify which objects where calling which methods. I also made it explicit that my code is inside a `$(document).ready` block.

---

**Solution**

In the end I went with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('head')[0].appendChild(
        $('<script />').attr('src', 'source.js').on('load', function() {
            …
        })[0]
    );
});
```

I think @istos was right in that something in `domManip` is breaking `load`.

Comment: Not sure why jQuery doesn't work. Using the native API certainly isn't a bad idea, but if you're supporting old browsers, some don't support the `document.head` property. You'll either need to select the `head` element from the DOM, or append it to the `document.body`.

Comment: ...also, I think old IE doesn't support `onload` for `script` elements. Not sure if jQuery fixes that.

Comment: @squint the clients do not include IE (thank goodness).

Comment: Wow, lucky you! :) I'd ditch jQuery altogether in that case.

Comment: Look into comments http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485535/why-wont-jquerys-load-event-fire-on-dynamically-inserted-script-elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is doing some funny business in its DOM manipulation code. If you look at jQuery's source, you'll see that it uses a method called `domManip()` inside the `append()` method.

This `domManip()` method creates a document fragment (*it looks like the node is first appended to a "safe" fragment*) and has a lot of checks and conditions regarding scripts. I'm not sure why it uses a document fragment or why all the checks about scripts exist but using the native `appendChild()` instead of jQuery's `append()` method fires the event successfully. Here is the code:

Live JSBin: http://jsbin.com/qubuyariba/1/edit

```
  var url = 'http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js';  
  var s = document.createElement('script');
  s.src = url;
  s.async = true;

  $(s).on('load', function(e) {
    console.log(!!window.d3); // d3 exists
    $(document.body).append('<h1>Load fired!</h1>');
  });

  $('head').get(0).appendChild(s);
```

### Update:

`appendChild()` is a well supported method and there is absolutely no reason not to use it in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is when you choose DOM appendChild, actually you called the function is `document.on('load',function(){});`, however when you choose jQuery append(), your code is `$('head').on('load', function(){})`.

The `document` and `head` are different.

You can type the code below:

  `$(document).find('head').append($('<script />').attr('src', 'source.js').end().on('load', function() {
       ...
  }));`

Comment: Look at the code again. `$('<script />').attr('src', 'source.js').on('load', function() {})` is passed to `$('head').append()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably make sure that the jquery append is fired when the document is ready. It could be that head is not actually in the dom when the append fires.

Comment: My code is already inside a `$(document).ready(…`, I didn't include that detail in my question.

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to ditch jquery completely, you could use zeptojs. Secondly, I couldn't find out how and why exactly this behavior is happening. Even though i felt answer was to be found in links below. So far i can tell that if you insert element before definig src element then load won't fire.

But for manual insertion it doesn't matter. (????)

However, what i was able to discover is that if you use `appendTo` it works.
**Code :**http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/tngxnkk7/

```
var $ele = $('<script />').attr('src', link).load(function(){ abc(); }) ).appendTo('head');
```

**New Info:** As is understood adding script tag to dom with src attribute on it, initiates the download process of script mentioned in src. Manual insertion causes page to load external script, using `append` or `appendTo` causes jquery to initiate downloading of external js file. But event is attached using jquery and jquery initiates download then event won't fire. But if it's the page itself initiates the download then it does. Even if event is added manually, without jquery, adding via jquery to dom won't make it fire.

Links in which i think should be the answer...

[Append Vs AppendChild JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15926325/append-vs-appendchild-jquery)

http://www.blog.highub.com/javascript/decoding-jquery-dommanip-dom-manipulation/

http://www.blog.highub.com/javascript/decoding-jquery-dommanip-dom-manipulation/

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L477-523

http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/

Comment: I'm not sure what this is doing? There is a switch from `$('<script />').on('load',…` in my code to `$(this).load(…` in your code. In context, the `this` object should be the window. Is this working because the window doesn't fire load until all the scripts have finished loading?